# Error: ! Problem while converting geom to grob. ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, interactive, ggiraph

I am running the examples at this [link](https://r-graph-gallery.com/308-interactive-circle-packing.html). After re-installing ggiraph, the same code that was working before, returns this error

```
Error:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check.length()`:
! 'gpar' element 'lwd' must not be length 0
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of ggiraph do you have? I am not reproducing the error.

Comment: Could you please share the exact code which returns this error with your `sessionInfo`?

Comment: I am experiencing the same error when using library(ggiraph). I am not able to update from 0.8.3 to 0.8.4 with R version 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ggplot2 are you using?  I was having trouble with an identical error from ggforce.  In the end I got everything working with R 4.2.2, ggplot2 3.4.0, ggiraph 0.8.4 and ggforce 0.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

Using `st_zm(shapefile)` should sove the problem.

Comment: I was having this issue, too - not with all of my shapefiles, just with one shapefile. The geometry for some polygons was MULTIPOLYGON Z (again, not all polygons - others were just MULTIPOLYGON). Using this answer solved the problem for me, by dropping the Z coordinate. I used this step as part of a pipe when reading the shapefile: 

shape <- read_sf("shape.shp") %>% st_zm()

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using geom_freqpoly in ggplot. There seemed to be a problem with xlim(). When I removed xlim() everything worked fine.
Restaring RStudio solved the problem for me.
R version 4.2.2
ggplot2_3.4.0